# SelectSingleNode returned null value

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to modify the xml file with PowerShell. When I try to select the target node with function SelectSingleNode, it returns null.

I searched in the Stack overflow and found a lot of answers stated that I need to pass the namespaceManager to SelectSingleNode. I tried but still no luck.

Here is the target xml file I need to modify:

```
<PolicyMetadata xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2012/04/ADFS">
  <RequireFreshAuthentication>false</RequireFreshAuthentication>
  <IssuanceAuthorizationRules>
    <Rule>
      <Conditions>
        <Condition i:type="GroupMembershipCondition">
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Values>
            <Value>S-1-5-21-297304416-3458697141-814752582-1120</Value>
          </Values>
        </Condition>
        <Condition i:type="MultiFactorAuthenticationCondition">
          <Operator>IsPresent</Operator>
          <Values />
        </Condition>
      </Conditions>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Conditions>
        <Condition i:type="LocationCondition">
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Values>
            <Value>192.168.1.0/24</Value>
            <Value>1.1.1.1</Value>
            <Value>2.2.2.2</Value>
          </Values>
        </Condition>
      </Conditions>
    </Rule>
  </IssuanceAuthorizationRules>
</PolicyMetadata>
```

I'm trying to select the node **Values** under **Condition i:type="LocationCondition"** .

Here is the PowerShell Script I used:

```
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load("C:\temp\policy1.xml")
$nsmgr = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNameSpace("x", "http://microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/MigrationTable")
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//x:Condition[@i:type='LocationCondition']/Values",$nsmgr)
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//Condition[@i:type='LocationCondition']/Values",$nsmgr)
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: "...I'm trying to modify the xml file..." Please edit your question, and add the following: (1) Input XML, (2) Desired output, (3) logic for modification.

Comment: Your default namespace has no prefix in your namespace manager. You need to add it and then prefix all of your nodes with it in the XPATH. If you don't care about namespaces, then you have the alternative `($xml.PolicyMetadata.IssuanceAuthorizationRules.Rule.Conditions.Condition | where type -eq 'LocationCondition').Values`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I'm not seeking the help of modifying that file. That's the goal I'll try to reach it by myself. In this post, I just need help to figure out how to use SelectSingleNode in PowerShell. So, I'm just introducing the background about why I need this function working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; you just have to manage your namespaces a little differently. Try it like this:

```
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2012/04/ADFS")
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

$targets = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//x:Condition[@i:type="LocationCondition"]//x:Values',$nsmgr)
$targets
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you Jack, it worked like a charm. I didn't realize that the "dummy namespace" must match the real namespace in the xml file. (In the other replies, they call it dummy namespace, so I think it can be anything) Another thing I didn't know is that the child element in the Xpath expression also needs the namespace prefix.

Comment: @StevenLee-MSFT Live and learn, as they say! Glad it worked for you.